# Can we make a Singleton class by making private getInstance method and public getter setter methods?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

Doesn't Singleton class just means enforcing of presence of a single instance of a class always? If that is the case, unlike the norm, can't we have getter-setter methods in it with private getInstance method?
In short, is below class an example of Singleton class? Why / Why not:-

```
public class MySingletonClass {
private MySingletonClass mySingletonClass;
private String name;
private MySingletonClass(){

}
private MySingletonClass getSingletonClassReference(){
    if(mySingletonClass==null){
        mySingletonClass = new MySingletonClass();
    }
    return mySingletonClass;
}

public static String getName() {
    return getSingletonClassReference().name;
}

public static setName(String name) {
    getSingletonClassReference().name = name;
}}
```

**EDIT**
Since above code gives compile time error, here is the modified class code. Question is still same, can't we have a public getter-setters and private getInstance method? Why not?

```
public class MySingletonClass {
private static MySingletonClass mySingletonClass;
private String name;
private MySingletonClass(){

}
private static MySingletonClass getSingletonClassReference(){
    if(mySingletonClass==null){
        mySingletonClass = new MySingletonClass();
    }
    return mySingletonClass;
}

public static String getName() {
    return getSingletonClassReference().name;
}

public static void setName(String name) {
    getSingletonClassReference().name = name;
}}
```

Comment: your latest edit of making the methods static will get you compiler errors of referencing a non-static member from a static context.  Define `private static MySingletonClass mySingletonClass;`.  Also, setName misses a return type, `void`

Comment: @Arjan Oh right. true. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: @Arjan Have put the modified code now. Please have a look.

Comment: Well, it works.  But you can not get a reference to the instance itself, so you'll always need to use the class like `MySingletonClass.setName("blahblah");`.  I agree with lakshman's answer that it's not very convenient, and with uniknow's answer that it's harder for users of the class to see it's a singleton.  This call looks like a call to a static utility method, while it's not.  A `MySingletonClass instance = MySingletonClass.getInstance();` will be clear to anyone who's even slightly familiar with Singletons.  This code not so.  But it's just opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is: can a `Singleton` be mutable? the answer is yes why not? but it needs to be `thread safe` which is not the case for now, indeed there are 2 issues in your code:

1. You don't prevent several threads to create your `singleton` which means that you could have several instances of your object which violates the contract of a `singleton`
2. You need to prevent reading and modifying the name at the same time otherwise your threads will get inconsistent values of your name.

First of all here is how to properly implement a `Singleton` that does lazy creation which is what you want obviously

```
public class MySingletonClass {
    // The constructor must be private to prevent external instantiation
    private MySingletonClass(){};
    /** The public static method allowing to get the instance */
    public static MySingletonClass getInstance() {
        return MySingletonClassHolder.INSTANCE;
    }
    /**
     * The static inner class responsible for creating your instance only on demand,
     * because the static fields of a class are only initialized when the class
     * is explicitly called and a class initialization is synchronized such that only 
     * one thread can perform it, this rule is also applicable to inner static class
     * So here INSTANCE will be created only when MySingletonClassHolder.INSTANCE 
     * will be called
     */
    private static class MySingletonClassHolder {
        private static final MySingletonClass INSTANCE = new MySingletonClass();
    }
}
```

This solves the point #1, for the point #2 you can either add the keyword `synchronized` in the declaration of both methods which are `getName` and `setName` or simply add the keyword `volatile` to the variable `name`. The last approach is non blocking so much faster, here is how this approach would look like:

```
public class MySingletonClass {

    private volatile String name;
    ...
```

Comment: As for point 1, Does Singleton principle also demands that even different thread not be able to create their own instances? If that is the case, I didn't get how your example takes care of this. Why can't multiple thread make their own instance in case of your example? :/

Comment: because a class initialization is only performed by one single thread so with this approach you know that you will create only one instance even if we have several threads calling getInstance() at the same time since only one thread will be allowed to initialize the inner class MySingletonClassHolder

Comment: Ok, so what if I make the getSingletonClassReference method synchronized? I think that will take care of the multiple thread making multiple instances, isn't it? Now, at least there will be only SINGLE instance at any point of time, right? So why not call it singleton? Why the need to avoid setters?

Comment: 1. This will be terrible in term of performances/scalability because anytime you want to access to your singleton you will need to acquire a lock which is why the approach that I propose above is interesting only the initialization is synchronized, later calls are lock free

Comment: "Why the need to avoid setters?"  which setters are you talking about?

Comment: Yes I agree, synchronization will always cause performance issues, but will it be a valid example of Singleton class or not? A synchronized static getInstance method, with public getter/setter methods?

Comment: By setters, I mean the "setters" in my class. In the normal, singleton classes examples, I never see any public getter/setters. Why?

Comment: yes if you add synchronized to the definition of your 3 methods (getSingletonClassReference, getName and setName), it will be a valid mutable singleton but poorly implemented

Comment: Thanks for confirming that. Just one more thing, why should setters be made synchronized? Isn't Singleton only about single object creation principle? Why should it worry about multiple threads seeing different values issue?

Comment: "I never see any public getter/setters. Why?" like which class? please give me concrete example?

Comment: I was talking about getter/setters in Singleton classes given as example on most websites/ Oracle Doc sites etc. They just don't have setters.

Comment: Like here - https://blogs.oracle.com/JavaFundamentals/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with

Comment: In java.awt.Toolkit you have getter/setter

Comment: "Why should it worry about multiple threads seeing different values issue?" because you could get bugs hard to find, if you share an object like a singleton you need to make it thread safe it is a basic principle to follow

Comment: I am only concerned about whether the class can be termed singleton or not. So does having a single instance, implies that the instance MUST not ever change it's state? Does it mean there shouldn't be any slight change in it's properties? Does the Singleton principle mandates this?

Comment: I answered it in my answer: can a Singleton be mutable? => Yes but it needs to be thread safe

Comment: Thanks. So that means if I take care of your point 1, my class will become a Singleton class. Thanks a lot, that's what I wanted to confirm. Let me just see if anyone else thinks contrary.

Comment: this is the best answer here, and it answers my major doubt of possibility of having setters in a singleton class, and of having private getInstance methods. Thanks for the nice answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on edited code, Still you can't guaranty of single instance creation of the MySingletonClass class. still its possible that two instances will create by two concurrent call. But In this example I think it can not impact of the result much else you have done some other process in your methods !!! that make sense.

Given your code:

consider A and B want to call setter method,
A call first.

getSingletonClassReference() will be called inside the setter, B at the same time call setter. A request arrive at **if(mySingletonClass==null){**
and it create an object. before that B arrive to the condition null checker and will be true, Basically it cause to create two instance of the object.
If we assume that B wait on    mySingletonClass = new MySingletonClass(); and A request reach at the  getSingletonClassReference().name = name; then B resume its execution, Then B override the name and A change will be ignored.

in your example it do not make sense but In a real world application it can cause bugs at run time and data lost.

better to apply synchronization in your code like this :

```
 public static Singleton getInstanceDC() 
    { 
       if (_instance == null) {
         // Single Checked 
         synchronized (Singleton.class) 
         { 
            if (_instance == null) 
            { // Double checked 
               _instance = new Singleton(); 
             } 
          }
        } 
     return _instance;
     }
```

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/05/double-checked-locking-on-singleton-in-java.html#ixzz4A4QZAlJH

Comment: Apologies. I wanted to make it static. Just changed the modifiers.

Comment: Yes, that's how the popular norm of creating a singleton class is. But I want to understand what's wrong with my class. Where is it violating the singleton principle? Isn't that just about existence of single object at any point of time? Why should a public getInstance method be of so much criticality?

Comment: you can't still guaranty the single creation of instance for the class I'll explain in the post

Comment: Check your answer now, hope this help u

Comment: Yes, in case of multithreading environment it will cause problem. But then I didn't get how it is taken care of, in the other case.

Comment: in which case do u mean ?

Comment: in case of pubic getInstance methods and no setters.

Comment: same problem, the logical bug is at instance creation thats mean in multi threading environment there is possibility of create more than one instance.

Comment: Ok, so what if I follow what you suggested? Synchronizin the getInstance method?

Comment: it will guaranty single instance creating. refer to the link below the answer, the solution is using a double check, means still two thread can pass   **if (_instance == null) {** but they will enter to synchronized block one by one. so second check will prevent the multi instance creation.

Answer (score 0):

A singleton means that there can be only 1 instance per JVM. That means that in your case the variable `mySingletonClass` has to be static, (private static MySingletonClass mySingletonClass;`) as well as the get/setname.

Regarding the norm, it is probably harder for users of your class to see that is a singleton.

Comment: doesn't null check ensures that there is only once instance created at any time?

Comment: No, because the variable `mySingletonCLass` is not static. In your code you already need an instance of the class. If classes and methods would be static, the null check would indeed guarantee that there can only be 1 instance.

Comment: yes true. I have modified the code a bit. Please have a look.

Comment: Yes now you have guaranteed that there can be only a `single` instance. Regarding whether you can use get/set instead of getInstance. That purely depends on the usage of the class. If you are using it as a configuration thing you could also use dependency injection and inject the configuration everywhere where required.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your method `getSingletonClassReference` public but the constructor is private so you cant create an object to access the method. So in this case you have make your method static so that other class can access the method without creating an object. But in your `getSingletonClassReferenc`e method the condition is not right. Here you can make a static counter to to check only one instance is created.

Comment: I made my method static now. Actually, I had missed it by mistake. So is it fine now? Also, why should this==null be used, and why static instance? Why isn't mySingletonClass==null suffice?

Comment: have put up the modified code. Please have a look. Is the current code fine now?

Comment: ok, actually static method can only have static data. so in this case you have make the instance variable static.

Comment: Yes true, I realized that later. And now I have modified the code. Can you please have a look at the modified code again, having static instance and static methods. Is it an example of Singleton class now?

Comment: yes it  is actually a singleton pattern. take a look at [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/singleton_pattern.htm) example. here you dont have to check whether the instance is null or not.

Comment: Yes, had seen that way of creating a Singleton class, but I was curious about this way, whether it is singleton or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That can be created.
But, the code you wrote above needs to be modified. The getter, setter,getSingletonClassReference() and mySingletonClass field should be static.
But, the important thing is this is not convenient.

Comment: actually, that's what I wanted to put in the beginning, somehow missed the static modified. Now I have put it, made the getter/setters static. Is it fine now?